# regex match string has repeated pattern without any delimiter

Tags: regex

I wnat a regex to match staring has repeated  pattern like this

```
abcabcabc // TRUE match is abc
mozmozmoz // TRUE  match is moz
mozpmoz // false
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible in a generic way with only using regex, because you have to describe the string you are searching for in some way.

However you can take this regex as a starting point:

```
^(\w+)\1+
```

`^` means start of line

`(\w+)` means at least one word character but up to unlimited, all captured in a group

`\1` is a back reference to the capture group

`+` means that the capture group must appear at least one time but can appear unlimited times

[see example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SWHlzG/1)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```
^(\w+)\1+$
```

The point is we use `\1` to match exactly what matched in our first group which is `(\w+)`.

click for [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bs27O4/1):

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:
`(\w+)\1`

`\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group